# docker-compose in docker-compose: Share network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am aware of sharing the docker socket by adding this volume `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` to the docker-compose file as proposed by [Using Docker-in-Docker for your CI or testing environment?](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)

I created this simple example/experiment setup to make it possible to start docker-compose in a docker-compose container, without sharing everything.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
services:
  manager:
    build:
      context: ./manager
    privileged: true

  ngnix:
    image: nginx:latest
```

**manager/Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN apt-get -y update \
  && apt-get install -y iputils-ping docker-compose

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["ping", "www.google.com"]
```

**manager/entrypoint.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e
service docker start
exec "$@"
```

**manager/docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
services:
  foobar:
    image: ruby:latest
```

Possible command now would be: `docker-compose up -d; docker-compose exec manager docker-compose run foobar /bin/bash`

For now, I did not manage to share the docker-compose network between the host and the one on the manager. This, off course, is how docker is intended to work per design. Therefore after executing the command above executing `ping ngnix` from the `foobar` container will not work.

***My question is:*** how can I make this work?

I tried adding `network: host`to the manager/docker-compose.yml in different ways but that did not work, or I was too stupid to do it correct.

Comment: Generally you don't try to run a new Docker daemon inside a container; it's difficult, it can get confusing which daemon you're talking to, and even the official documentation discourages it.  See the [official `docker` Docker Hub image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/), including the "generally not recommended" line in the first sentence of its extended documentation.

Comment: If you succeeded at this, it'd be a totally isolated Docker with its own networks, container storage, _etc._  If you want to share things with the host Docker you have to actually use the host Docker by bind-mounting the socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Maze points out possibly the only solution is to share the socket. More reading information on that here:

- [Using Docker-in-Docker for your CI or testing environment?](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)
- [Docker in Docker?](https://itnext.io/docker-in-docker-521958d34efd)